# Fixing performance issues when looping through MySQL results in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm working on a virtual game board style game in which players get points on a certain area of the board. (Take it easy on me now as I only do this as a hobby so I might be doing this in the worst way possible)

I have 3 tables. One stores all the player information (eg. id, screenname). A second stores all the Area information (eg. id, x, y) and a third stores how many points each player has in each area (eg. id, playerid, areaid, points). In order to create a "leaderboard" I'm looping through all the players, then within that loop I'm also looping through all the areas, then finally within that second loop, I get the leader of that area and see if that matches the current player in the first loop, if so I increment a counter, then store it into an array. (See code below with some commenting)

I looked into MySQL caching, but I dont have access to a lot of the server options, as well as would like to keep as much of the results as live as possible, so caching may not be the right way to go.

My question is whether or not I'm doing this properly. Currently there is only around 10 players, and approx. 500 areas. I'm finding the below script already takes about 5-8 seconds to run. Potentially there could be millions of areas, so such a long delay in processing could be catastrophic (for the leaderboard anyway). Am I going about this the right way, and/or is there a better way to do this?

```
<?php
    $leaders = array();

    //Loop through all the players
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM players";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        //save player information into variables
        $playerId = $row['id'];
        $playerScreenName = $row['screenname'];

        //Reset the area counter
        $AreaCount = 0;
        $leader = array();

        //Loop through all areas
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM areas";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2) or die(mysqli_error($con));
        while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
            $areaId = $row2['id'];

            //Get the player with the most points in that area
            $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM points WHERE areaid='$areaId' ORDER BY totalpoints DESC LIMIT 1";
            $result3 = mysqli_query($con, $sql3) or die(mysqli_error($con));
            while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {
                $leaderOfArea = $row3['playerid'];

                //See if the leader of the area is the same player we are looping through
                if ($playerId == $leaderOfArea) {
                    //if it is, then increment the counter
                    $AreaCount++;
                }
            }
        }
        //Store the leader information into an array to be output later
        $leader['screenname'] = $playerScreenName;
        $leader['areacount'] = $AreaCount;

        $leaders[] = $leader;
    }

    // sort leaders by score
    usort($leaders, 'compare_areacount');
?>
```

Comment: From a quick look, couldn't you eliminate iterating over the players? If you just process every area and find the player scores for that area or find the leader for that area then that would seem to do the job if you increment some associative array with player ID as the keys. Even so, with potentially millions of areas this could get long but that seems unavoidable

Comment: Yes there clearly seems to be a performance issue. You are looping through all areas inside all players and finding if that player is the leader of the area points wise. Better would be looping through all players first and storing their info in variables, and then you can get areas and their leader ids directly using 1 mysql query, and loop through them to fill up your areas array.

Answer (score 0):

There is overhead of opening database connections, and when you do it in a loop, you exacerbate the problem (and then when you add a loop inside of that, you make it that much worse). Instead, restructure it as one query using a Join or Subquery.

[This post has some specifics.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643225/php-alternative-to-using-a-query-within-a-loop)

Answer (score 0):

I think this code can help. You might have to change the sql queries with appropriate column names you need.

```
<?php

$leaders = array();

//Loop through all the players
$sql = "SELECT * FROM players";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

$players = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    //save player information into variables
    $players[$row['id']] = array($row['screenname'], 0);
    // number 0 will be the count of how many times this player is the leader
}

$sql = "SELECT Area.id, Area.name, (SELECT Pts.playerid FROM `points`"
    . " AS Pts WHERE Pts.areaid=Area.id ORDER BY totalpoints"
    . " DESC LIMIT 1) AS `leader_id` FROM `areas` AS Area";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

$areas = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    $areas[$row[0]] = $row;

    // $row[2] will contain leader_id
    // index 1 corresponds to the second element in player values array
    $players[$row[2]][1]++;
}

// now if you want to print:
foreach ($areas as $area_id => $area) {
    echo "Area id: " . $area_id . ", name: " . $area[1] . ", leader_id: " . $area[2] . "<br /><br />";
}

foreach ($players as $player_id => $player) {
    echo "Player id: " . $player_id . ", name: " . $player[0] . ", No of areas this player is a leader of: " . $player[1] . "<br /><br />";
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what the sql query does? It didnt work for me, but I have a feeling that something got lost in translation when I tried to use it with different column names. I've never seen a nested SELECT within a SELECT like that before, so I'm intrigued to figure out how it works as this might help me big time in the long run